# How to model composite primary key, containing foreign key?

Tags: java, sqlite, jpa, serializable, composite-key

I have the following relation

[image]

As you see, details table of `feature_affinities` has composite key (`feature_id`, `zoom`), of of which components it a foreign key, referring master table of `features`.

I wrote

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "features")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "subtype_id", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public class Feature {

   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
   @GeneratedValue(generator="sqlite")
   @TableGenerator(name="sqlite", table="sqlite_sequence",
      pkColumnName="name", valueColumnName="seq",
      pkColumnValue="features")
//   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Getter
   @Setter
   private long id;

...

@Embeddable
public class FeatureAffinitiesKey implements Serializable {

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "feature_id")
   @Getter
   @Setter
   private Feature feature;

   @Column(name = "zoom")
   @Getter
   @Setter
   private Long zoom;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "feature_affinities")
public class FeatureAffinities {

   @Getter
   @Setter
   @EmbeddedId
   private FeatureAffinitiesKey key;

...
```

Is this correct?

I am confused, that it claimed me to declare `FeatureAffinitiesKey` serializable. But since it contains `Feature` fiels, it will cause `Feature` should be serializable too and also all compound related classes inside `Feature` too.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

This is what the JPA spec calls a "derived identity". You should define your `FeatureAffinities` classes slightly differently:

```
@Embeddable
public class FeatureAffinitiesKey implements Serializable {

   @Column(name = "feature_id")
   @Getter
   @Setter
   private long featureId; // corresponds to the type of Feature's PK

   @Column(name = "zoom")
   @Getter
   @Setter
   private Long zoom;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "feature_affinities")
public class FeatureAffinities {

   @Getter
   @Setter
   @EmbeddedId
   private FeatureAffinitiesKey key;

   @MapsId("featureId") // maps 'featureId' attribute of embedded id
   @ManyToOne
   @Getter
   @Setter
   private Feature feature;

   ...
}
```

Note the `@MapsId` annotation on `FeatureAffinities.feature`.

Derived identities are discussed in the JPA 2.1 spec in section 2.4.1.